# Complex structure on a subset of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry

Assume that $F\colon V\to V$ is an operator on a real vector field $V$ such that $F^3=-F$. How to prove that $F$ projects $V$ on $W \subset V$ where it satisfies $F^2=-\operatorname{Id}$?

The only thing that I can notice is that if $F^2\cdot F = (-\operatorname{Id})F= -F$ then by multiplying it with $F^{-1}$ on the right we obtain the identity $-\operatorname{Id} = -\operatorname{Id}$.

Comment: You can't necessarily multiply by $F^{-1}$ because $F$ might not be invertible. If it is invertible, then by multiplying both sides of $F^3 = -F$ by $F^{-1}$ you get $F^2 = -\operatorname{Id}$ so $F$ is a complex structure on $V$. In general, it will define a complex structure only on a subspace $W$ of $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $V$ is finite dimensional. Let us show that $V = \operatorname{ker}(F) \oplus \operatorname{im}(F)$. By rank-nullity, it is enough to show that $\ker(F) \cap \operatorname{im}(F) = \{ 0 \}$ so let $Fv \in \ker(F) \cap \operatorname{im}(F)$. Then $F(Fv) = F^2 v = 0$ but then $0 = F^3 v = -F v$ so $Fv = 0$. Now set $W = \operatorname{im}(F)$. If $u = Fv \in W$ then $F^2 u = F^3 v = -Fv = -u$ so $\left( F|_{W} \right)^2 = -\operatorname{Id}|_{W}$.